# Layout problems with customized FieldEditor (Eclipse Preference Page)

Tags: eclipse, grid-layout, preferences

I try to create my own FieldEditor (as I have to fill combobox values dynamically). So my class extends 'FieldEditor'. My preference page needs 3 of these fields which then look like this (2nd,3rd and 4th field-editors; the 'select kernel' ones).

[image]

Obviously something goes wrong with the layout. All fields should look like the 3rd field - using the full space.

```
@Override
protected void adjustForNumColumns(int numColumns) {
    ((GridData) c_top.getLayoutData()).horizontalSpan = numColumns;
}

@Override
protected void doFillIntoGrid(Composite parent, int numColumns) {

    /* Layout comments:
     * 
     * component are sequentially filled into numColumns
     * by default each component will use 1 column
     * GridData can be set to use more that one columns
     */

    GridData gd = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false);
    gd.horizontalSpan = numColumns;

    c_top = parent;
    c_top.setLayoutData(gd);

    c_group = new Composite(c_top, SWT.BORDER);

    GridLayout newgd = new GridLayout(2, false);
    c_group.setLayout(newgd);
    c_group.setLayoutData(gd);

    // kernel spec combo

    Label comboLabel = new Label(c_group, SWT.NONE);
    comboLabel.setText("Select kernel");
    gd = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.TOP, false, false);
    gd.horizontalSpan = numColumns - 1;
    comboLabel.setLayoutData(gd);

    c_kernelCombo = new Combo(c_group, SWT.READ_ONLY);
    gd = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false);
    //gd.horizontalSpan = 1;
    c_kernelCombo.setLayoutData(gd);     
}
```

I even tried a simpler layout without using a group but then all my field-editors only used 2 cells of the grid (which looks a bit funny with 3 columns given by the other field editors.

I have no idea how to fix it . Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the same instance of `GridData` (`gd`) on two controls - this is **not** allowed. You must create a new `GridData` for each control.

In any case you should not be setting the layout data on the `parent` Composite - that doesn't belong to your code.

Comment: Following you suggestions did not solve the problem. I came to a solution (though I don't know if it's the correct solution). I will explain as a separate answer and I am happy about further comments.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution but I don't know whether it's correct:

1) I made the mistake to create all FieldEditors of that page with the same parent, though the docs say to retrieve a new parent for each field editor with `getFieldEditorParent()`

2) I guess, I misunderstood the meaning of `adjustForNumColumns(int numColumns)`. I asume, it should adapt the horizontalSpan of the controls which are affected by a change of the number of columns. Now my code looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void adjustForNumColumns(int numColumns) {
    ((GridData) c_kernelCombo.getLayoutData()).horizontalSpan = numColumns-1;
}

@Override
protected void doFillIntoGrid(Composite parent, int numColumns) {

    // kernel spec combo
    Label comboLabel = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);
    comboLabel.setText("Select kernel");
    GridData gd = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.TOP, false, false);
    gd.horizontalSpan = 1;
    comboLabel.setLayoutData(gd);

    c_kernelCombo = new Combo(parent, SWT.READ_ONLY);
    gd = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false);
    gd.horizontalSpan = numColumns - 1;
    c_kernelCombo.setLayoutData(gd);     
}
```